# OSX: Shortcuts that only work in certain apps

Tags: macos, mac, keyboard-shortcuts

I noticed there seem to be groups of apps that either all work or all don't work with certain groups of shortcuts. Off the top of my head, I can think of 4 such shortcuts for 2 kinds of operations:

- Going to top/bottom of file. Fn-Cmd-Left/Right work in Microsoft Word, Eclipse and RubyMine, but not Textmate or Chrome. Cmd-Up/Down work in Textmate or Chrome, but not Microsoft Word, Eclipse and RubyMine.
- Deleting forward. Fn-Del works in Microsoft Word, Eclipse and RubyMine but not Textmate or Chrome. Ctrl-D works in Textmate or Chrome but not Microsoft Word, Eclipse and RubyMine.

I'm guessing it has to do with the frameworks used to build each app, but what frameworks might they be? What OSX feature is responsible for this? And if one wanted to make those shortcuts work in every app, what should one do?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, these shortcuts are the developer's responsibility regardless of the framework or programming language.  Microsoft is notorious for incompatibility of keyboard shortcuts within their own apps and even more so between Windows and OS X.

But you can mitigate some of their faults by creating your own shortcuts in System Preferences.  This is well documented.  Here's a snip from Apple's Support site

---

1. Choose Apple menu > **System Preferences**, then click **Keyboard**.
2. Click **Shortcuts**, select **App Shortcuts**, then click **Add (+)**.
3. Choose an app from the Application pop-up menu. *If you want to set the same key
   combination for a menu command that appears in many apps, choose All
   Applications.*

   **If the app you want to select does not appear** in the
   list, choose Other and locate it using the Open dialog. Some apps
   may not allow you to set keyboard shortcuts.
4. **Type the menu command** for which you want to set a keyboard shortcut in the Menu Title
   field. *You must type the command exactly as it appears in the
   Application menu, including ellipses and any other punctuation.* An
   ellipsis is a special character that looks like three periods. To
   type an ellipsis, press Option-semicolon, or use the Character
   Viewer. It may be difficult to know whether the command is written
   in the menu with a real ellipsis or with three periods, so if one
   does not work, try the other.
5. Click in the **Keyboard Shortcut** field, press the key combination that you want to assign to the menu command, then click **Add**. You can’t use each type of key (for
   example, a letter key) more than once in a key combination.
6. **Quit and restart any apps you’re using** for the new keyboard shortcut to take effect.

*If you assign a keyboard shortcut that already exists for another command or another app, **your new shortcut won’t work.*** Find the menu command that’s using it and reassign the keyboard shortcut for that item.

---

Hope this helps.

Comment: So you're saying Microsoft Word, Eclipse and RubyMine have nothing in common between their implementations? That was what I was curious about. I always felt like those apps don't integrate into OSX as seamlessly as e.g. Chrome.

In any case, none of the shortcuts I listed are menu items. Am I just SOL then? Thanks.